# С какого запроса следует начинать авторизацию на DropBox?

Tags: http, https, oauth, request, dropbox

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане!

Изучаю документацию по протоколу Oauth 1.0 для DropBox, но не могу понять, с какого запроса следует начинать сеанс обращения к серверу DropBox. В документации написано, что первый запрос должен содержать следующие параметры:

> - oauth_consumer_key: The Consumer Key.
> - oauth_signature_method:
>     The signature method the Consumer used to sign the request.
> - oauth_signature:
>     The signature as defined in Signing Requests.
> - oauth_timestamp:
>     As defined in Nonce and Timestamp.
> - oauth_nonce:
>     As defined in Nonce and Timestamp.
> - oauth_version:
>     OPTIONAL. If present, value MUST be 1.0 . Service Providers MUST assume the protocol version to be 1.0 if this parameter is not present. Service Providers’ response to non-1.0 value is left undefined.
> - Additional parameters:
>     Any additional parameters, as defined by the Service Provider.

Для вычисления подписи предлагается использовать PLAINTEXT, HMAC-SHA1 или RSA-SHA1. Методом PLAINTEXT ничего не получилось, как не пыталась отправлять запросы, сервер всё время возвращал ошибку "Not authorized".

Решила попробовать создавать подпись с помощью HMAC-SHA1, но не понятно, что будет являться входным параметром, а что ключом. Подскажите ещё, пожалуйста, какой нужно отправлять метод: POST или GET, куда передавать параметры: в строку запроса или в тело запроса?

Ссылка на рефы DropBox: http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process

Пример:

```
    wstring url = L"https://www.dropbox.com/home/request_token";
    wstring oauth_nonce;
    CreateRequestParam(oauth_nonce);
    wstring oauth_callback = L"";
    wstring oauth_consumer_key = L"my App key";
    wstring oauth_consumer_secret = L"my App secret";
    wstring oauth_signature_method = L"PLAINTEXT";
    wstring oauth_timestamp = to_wstring(*(double*)time);
    wstring oauth_version = L"1.0";
    wstring oauth_signature = oauth_consumer_secret + L"&";
    wstring params = L"oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key +
                     L"&oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method +
                     L"&oauth_signature=" + oauth_signature +
                     L"&oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp +
                     L"&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce +
                     L"&oauth_version=" + oauth_version;

    int err = PostRequest(url, params);
```

На указанный url отправляю HTTP POST запрос, в теле передаю параметры, указанные выше. Должны возвращаться out_token и outh_secret, но возвращается страница в html-формате, в которой нет ни того, ни другого. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, актуален ли еще вопрос, попробую ответить.

Первый запрос на адрес `https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token`

Пример:

```
POST https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Host: api.dropbox.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="973quph3jxdgqoe",oauth_nonce="105816471209",oauth_signature="wloizpn331cc8zd&",oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_timestamp="Wed%2C%2013%20May%202015%2015%3A37%3A53%20%2B0000",oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

В ответ получаете `oauth_token`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 15:46:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...
Content-Length: 64

oauth_token_secret=LZl8HyVRQuP1ifON&oauth_token=RS4XReiBykw8WHNz
```

Затем отправляете пользователя в браузер на страничку `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=RS4XReiBykw8WHNz`

Пользователь нажимает кнопочку Allow.

Затем выполняете запрос на второй URL (подписываете его уже с использованием полученного ранее `oauth_token_secret`:

`https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token`

```
POST https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Host: api.dropbox.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="973quph3jxdgqoe",oauth_nonce="847334669",oauth_signature="wloizpn331cc8zd&LZl8HyVRQuP1ifON",oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_timestamp="Wed%2C%2013%20May%202015%2015%3A46%3A46%20%2B0000",oauth_token="RS4XReiBykw8WHNz",oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

И получаете в ответ токен, который будете использовать при последующих запросах:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 15:46:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: keep-alive
...
Content-Length: 76

oauth_token_secret=32mdalirxxxxa8j&oauth_token=yx8f9rdxxxxj8dia&uid=1921xxxx
```

[Пример авторизации на Dropbox](https://github.com/zenden2k/image-uploader/blob/master/Data/Scripts/dropbox.nut#L122)

[Пример OAuth авторизации на Flickr с подписыванием запроса HMAC-SHA1](https://github.com/zenden2k/image-uploader/blob/master/Data/Scripts/flickr.nut#L129)

Comment: спасибо вам!))) очень хороший подробный ответ!)))